# Extending print function in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging

I want to extend my print function so that it automatically only prints if the app is in `kdebugmode`. I also want to be able to print several values using the following syntax, similar to Python
`print(a,b,c)`. I was wondering if this is possible and if it's an okay practice.

I couldn't find information on altering native functions in Flutter.

Comment: rather than print you can use `debugPrint()`. It will only print data when you're in debug mode and you can print multiple data by this syntax. `debugPrint("$a $b $c");`
Even you can write comments with this  `debugPrint("data1 $a.  data2 $b  data3 : $c");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible ways,

1. You can create a custom function:

   ```
   void myPrint(Object? a, [Object? b, Object? c]) {
     if (kDebugMode) {
    String output = a.toString();
    if (b != null) {
      output += ' $b';
    }
    if (c != null) {
      output += ' $c';
    }
    print(output);
    }
   }
   ```

   And you can use it as `myPrint(a,b,c);`

---

2. As @Rohan Jariwala suggested, you can possibly use `debugPrint()`, and you can use it as

   ```
   debugPrint('$a $b $c')
   ```

Comment: debugPrint is a part of Flutter framework. Importing it is a bit inconvenient. For example, in data access layer

Comment: Yes I agree with you @AndreyGordeev.

Comment: @AndreyGordeev Your lower layer shouldn't be choosing on its own how to output diagnostics.  Your lower layer should use, say, a `void Function(String)` that a higher layer specifies.  Or use `package:logging`.